# Difference between load time is too much for 1user and 100 users

Tags: jmeter

I am running jmeter script.For one user getting load time as 2 sec and for 100 users getting load time as 14 sec.Ramp up period is 1 sec..The difference between load time is too much.How I can solve this?

Comment: first add more details about **what** is taking more time, try to find the exact code/SQL/network/... issue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about website speeds and concurrent requests, there are many things you can do depending on your application.

Some things to consider are:

- Partial of full page caching
- Database optimization
- Better, faster hardware
- Etc

In my experience as a developer, block or page caching is usually the big one and can (depending on your app) have a huge 99% improvement overall, assuming you didn't make any cricital mistakes in other areas.