# How to calculate Load time in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am calculating load time for one user and for 100 users.It gives load time for 1 user as 2 sec and for 100 users as 14 sec...Why this much of difference..Am I wrong.Can anybody explain how to calculate load time in j meter. Is there any setting which I have to do in j meter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between load time is too much for 1user and 100 users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963785/difference-between-load-time-is-too-much-for-1user-and-100-users)

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behaviour as you increase the load generation you will see the downgrade in the performance depends upon your host.

I would suggest to look into [Windows Performance Monitor](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-performance-monitor-windows-10)

Whenever you start generating load on an application (using any tool), Performance monitor (also known as perfmon) will provide you all the details regarding your Host.

You can set your own performance counters to monitor specific process.

Comment: But I don't know whether I am on right track or not...So How I can find out that...My result is correct or not?

Comment: What are the statistics you got from the host? Just observe the Windows Performance monitor. For example: Just observe the CPU usage before generating load and after starting your test, observe the CPU usage.It will definitely increase. If it increases that means you're script is fine and generating the load.

Answer (score 0):

Need to specify the question, is it a web application you are trying to testing? Do you know the cache has been used in your chrome browser. Treat Jmeter as a protocol tool rather than smart browser.